# Converting a private key to PKCS#8

Tags: openssl, pkcs#8

I've generated a key using OpenSSL:

openssl genrsa -out my.key 2048

How to convert this key to PKCS#8 so that I can import it easily in .NET using `CngKey.Import`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in my.key -out my.pkcs8.key -nocrypt
```